# How to build project like Eclipse Clean on Maven pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng

I need help on running maven project. I can run the project on Eclipse, and I tried to deploy / run it on Jenkins CI but without success.

I made a maven project with custom folder structure (not following the default).

Below is the structure:

[image: structure]

I can run the project successfully through Eclipse by cleaning the project first where I believe Eclipse build all java files for me. Below is the 'target' folder looks like after I clean the project through Eclipse (not maven clean)

[image]

However, when I delete the content of 'target' folder, and run maven -clean and maven -install I received an error like this:

[image]

I believe it's because I did not set anything on the pom.xml about building all java classes. However I do not know how to do it ? Can you help me? Changing structure is avoided right now. Thanks

Below is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>bukalapak</groupId>
<artifactId>bukalapak</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.46.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.46.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.9.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

<!--  <resources>
<resource>
<directory>src/bukalapak</directory>
</resource>
</resources> -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
             <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
            <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testsuite/TestSuiteBukalapak.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why not using the standard layout?!

Comment: @SilviuBurcea to increase readibility :(

Comment: Not a good reason, cause the default maven layout is widely familiar so i would say this is the best...and don't use your own...which brings you to so much configuration which is the wrong way in Maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/). Example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the default directory structure, you have to configure the source directory appropriately. In your case, the correct configuration would be:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

Otherwise Maven would look in the default folder structure.